# Moving the button in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have buttons with letters and I need to make a word out of them, please tell me how can I move this button to the field after clicking on the button with a letter? Or is it better to do something differently?

[i.e. by pressing the button with the letter S, the button disappears from that place and moves to the field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhG6X.png)

Comment: Please include more details. Do you want to move the button with a script or in Unity itself? Which and how many buttons should be moved where (maybe post an image) ?

Comment: @Банан, Added, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of new to Unity but this is what I think you would need to do.

If you want the letter S to move when you press the SKey, you would probably want something like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        MoveS();
    }
}

void MoveS()
{
    objectS.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(newXPos, newYPos, newZPos);
}
```

where the `new Vector 3` is the position where you want the letter to move. You would probably need to repeat this for each letter you want to use the keyboard for.

---

If you want the letter S to move when you hover over it and click on it, you would probably want something like this:

```
public void MoveS()
{
    objectS.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(newXPos, newYPos, newZPos);
}
```

and then assign it to the 'On Click()' section on Unity for the button.
[Here's what that section looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMAmV.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to move, you could do

```
public GameObject letter; //define the letter
public GameObject emptyField; // define empty field
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        letter.transform.position = emptyField.transform.position; //letter moves to field
    }
}
```

You could make it whatever key you want by replacing S with whatever